# Reload app in iOS simulator using Command-R not working

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

I am using TabBarIOS component in React native. If I press Command-R, the reload of the app is not happening. I use the "Shake Gesture" to show the menu and then click Reload on the context menu to reload the app.

Is there a way to get Command-R to work with TabBarIOS component in React native?

Comment: be sure that app is installed on simulator in debug mode not release mode

Comment: tick on as image : [tick on as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3Yjx.png)

Answer (score 37):

When I had this problem, I had it from the beginning so it probably wasn't due to a specific component. However, it might work for you, too:

With the iOS Simulator in focus, select the menu item **Hardware > Keyboard > Send Menu Keyboard Shortcuts to Device**.

In addition, I use the Colemak keyboard layout and found that after making the selection above I also had to use the <kbd>R</kbd> as printed on my keyboard keys for the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> command instead of the one I would use based on the Colemak layout.

Comment: I believe this also relies on **Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard** being selected, but that was already on for me by default.

Comment: This seemed to knock something loose and make it respond a little better, but also broke Command-Tab when trying to switch away from the Simulator. I unchecked the option again and it seems Command-R continued to be responsive. Oh Apple.

Comment: It started working after I select *I/O > Send Keyboard Input to Device* for Simulator Version 11.4 (921.9), SimulatorKit 581.9, CoreSimulator 704.12

Comment: This is now under I/O > Input > Send Keyboard Input to Device

Answer (score 23):

@burak-karasoy comments help me, I was building App in Release mode which does not allow hot reloading. To switch build you should go to the Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme and select Debug for Build Configuration.

[image]

UPDATE: Sometimes <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> doesn't properly work, but you always can use `Shake` option.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Try the simulator menu to send keyboard input to the device.

`I/O` > `Input` > `Send Keyboard Input to Device`

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will simulate a shake that will open the developer menu regardless if you have `I/O` > `Input` > `Send Keyboard Input to Device` toggled On or Off.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / ... will only work when `I/O` > `Input` > `Send Keyboard Input to Device` is checked!

Official Documentation: https://docs.expo.io/workflow/development-mode/#showing-the-developer-menu

Comment: `I/O > Input > Send Keyboard Input to Device is checked!`
that was the answer for me, thanks man

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried checking the option, "Connect Hardware Keyboard". 
Under the <kbd>Hardware</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> menu?

Answer (score 9):

first use `⇧+⌘+K`

then use  `⌘+R`

hope it works

Answer (score 7):

`cmd+r` and `cmd+d` just fail to work intermittently in my experience.  Sometimes I need to press cmd+r 4-5 times to get a refresh.

The 'shake' option though seems to work very consistently.  So I have Keyboard Maestro set up to remap `cmd+d` to `ctrl+cmd+z`, and remap `cmd+r` to:

1. `ctrl+cmd+z`
2. Pause .5 seconds for menu to appear
3. Click the `reload` button image

This is working very consistently.  If you're not using keyboard maestro I'd just recommend always using `ctrl+cmd+z` if the other commands don't consistently work for you.  Though I wish they would!

Answer (score 2):

Please try to press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to toggle the software keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing above works out, then in `Simulator menu`, go to `Devices` and click on `Restart`. This restarts the device itself.

[image]

Now go back to your terminal (where you're running expo) and press i (for ios simulator) and it should open up the app again.

[image]

Comment: sim was stuck, restart fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a note:

I just discovered that you'll probably always experience intermittent refresh with `⌘ + R` because IOS simulator's keyboard shortcut for screen recording is `⌘ + R` as well, thus the conflict.

You could try remapping refresh command to avoid that.