# React-Native iOS Simulator Command + R Not Working

Tags: ios, react-native, refresh, simulator

Today suddenly and issue started to happen and the Command + R does not refresh the app anymore.

I have tried many solutions but none of them seem to work.

- Checking the **Debug Mode**
- Hardware Keyboard settings
- Resetting the simulator

I am using RN 0.57.1.

Very frustrating.

Comment: reset simulator

Comment: This is not working as I have mentioned above.

Comment: What Hardware Keyboard Settings did you check? When I had this problem I had to enable a couple of them to get it to work. It would be helpful to others with similar problems to know what else they could try.

Comment: Please check these answers; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939831/reload-app-in-ios-simulator-using-command-r-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
 pod 'yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/'
 pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native/', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'ART',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTLinkingIOS',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTVibration',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'DevSupport',
  'CxxBridge',
]
...
```

After I installed the pod file like above, and run the project on iOS simulator, I noticed cmd+R doesn't work, I also tried to fix it as you mentioned above, but failed.

[please check the ios instructions above ios manual setup](https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper/blob/master/installation_guide/README.md#ios)

so I removed other libraries except specific framework using on the current project, and deleted other targets except main target. 
Finally, it works. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my own issue by commenting out **use_frameworks!**.

For some reason iOS builds fail when **use_frameworks!** is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It may be work for others also, create project with "init" it will work. This error usually happens with "crna".