# Simulator 10.2.1 command + R not working in react-native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, simulator

After updating XCode and simulator to 10.2.1, Command + R shortcut stopped working. While Command + D still works (for two different React-native apps). It is debug mode and tried all solutions from here [Reload app in iOS simulator using Command-R not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939831/reload-app-in-ios-simulator-using-command-r-not-working) and reinstall of watchman but nothing helps.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually pretty simple to solve, stop your app on Xcode, stop and close your Metro Bundler and Simulator and then run it again, issue solved.