# Why does React Native iOS emulator's reload shortcut sometimes stop working?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, ios-simulator, emulation

Occasionally the `Cmd+R` keyboard shortcut to reload the React Native iOS emulator stops working. The `Cmd+D` command to open the developer menu still works, and I can reload from there, and when I close and re-run the emulator `Cmd+R` works again, but I'm just curious why it might be that it stops working.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue. Seems to be an iOS 13.3+ simulator issue as you can see in this thread:

[iOS Simulator CMD+R CMD+D Shake doesn't work at all after some time](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27384)

As an alternative, `command + ctrl + z` still works to the access development menu.

Answer (score 2):

To make `cmd-R` work again, press `cmd-option-K`.

This corresponds to using the Menu Bar and choosing, `I/O` , `Input`, `send keyboard input to device`. I suspect that without this setting `cmd-R` is interpreted as `Record Screen` by the emulator (and that command is often disabled).

[Source of solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27384#issuecomment-612016268)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below option it will help you.

[Reload app in iOS simulator using Command-R not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939831/reload-app-in-ios-simulator-using-command-r-not-working)

command + ctrl + z is alternate option