# Cmd+r Recording the simulator instead of reloading the app in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

As you know new feature recording simulator has been around for 14.5 simulators, however the problem is that it's set to cmd+r, we can not reload the app using cmd+r anymore, can we fix it or can we disable recording video feature? thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can override the shortcut of **Record Video** from **Cmd + R** to **Cmd + Shift + R**.

The following screenshots are the way how to do it.

[image: Run System Preferences...]

[image: Show keyboard settings]

[image: Click add custom shortcut]

[image: Select application]

Scroll down to the bottom and click **Other...**

Click shortcut key **Cmd + Shift + G**

Input **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app**

[image: Scroll down to the bottom and click other]

[image: Override shortcut key]

[image: Select simulator]

[image]

[image: Final screen]

[image: You can confirm the final shortcut key]

Comment: This answer is brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: Life saver! Thank you!

Comment: Amazing and well-documented! Great answer. Also saves me accidentally screen recording for *hours* without realising it!

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great solution! Incredible that we have to go to these lengths to fix such an issue...

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried below option

command + ctrl + z

this might help you

[Reload app in iOS simulator using Command-R not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939831/reload-app-in-ios-simulator-using-command-r-not-working)